# Performance-issue in WP-admin with a lot of posts

Tags: wp-admin, performance

When clicking on "Manage posts" to view all posts in WP Admin, it takes waaay to long. 
This is a new WP-site, but we are importing posts from an old site, and currently we have 3,376 posts at the site. But the goal is to import between 10-15.000 articles.

However, if WP is going to reduce the performance like this - it is really critical. 
It loads 1.5 - 3 minutes (!) before anythis shows up..

The overall performance of the site it self is really good, but the admin-area for posts is a disaster.

So;
1. WHY is the performance so bad
2. How can we make it faster?

Comment: I have around 3000 posts (a test environment) and the pages load fine both in admin and front end. Are you sure you don't have a plugin or something that's doing some expensive queries on the administration side?

Comment: I have +10.000 posts on my private weblog, that manage posts screen loads in under 3 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I tried now to disable a plugin that is related to posts and such, witch is Magic Fields. Once turned off, the manage posts-screen was loaded almost instantly. 

So, I guess I will try to get some answers/advice from the developer of the plugin. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting the front end / published site is fast but not the admin.

Have tried turning off all plugins?

Can you setup a 2nd "sandbox" site and import all the content into that? Or try a cheap but fast host like MDD hosting and setup a test site there for $7/month.

If you have a good a developer on staff, they might be able to see if the issue is with database performance using this plugin to profile the database...

http://tierra-innovation.com/wordpress-cms/plugins/wpdb-profiling/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sample problem with a local install? It sounds like you're on a shard service with a pretty large site